# What is the Future<T> class in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am new in Flutter but not in React Native and Ionic. What is the Future class in the context of the Flutter framework?  Could someone explain it in detail? Because I saw it has used quite frequently. For example in this AlertDialog doc.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html

Comment: There is a [good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTS-ap9_aXc) from Flutter team explaining it

Comment: also see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Future` is basically the Dart equivalent of `Promise`, from JS.

Answer (score 1):

An object representing a delayed computation.

A Future is used to represent a potential value, or error, that will be available at some time in the future.

[More info here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html)

So if some function returns `Future` it means some actions will made asynchronously and you can get result in callback using `then` or can wait for result using keyword `await` and continue to perform your code after getting result

Answer (score 0):

Most simple explanation is

> Future are **objects** that allow you to specify a function that will be executed when the calling function ( the one who called future) is done with a certain operation.